# Autoprefixer in laravel mix

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, gulp, laravel-mix

Laravel mix is not compiling autoprefix. output.css is same as input.css 
- webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.styles('resources/css/input.css', 'public/css/output.css')
    .options({
        postCss: [
            require('autoprefixer')({
                browsers: ['last 40 versions'],
            })
        ]
    });
```

- input.css

```
.example {
    display: grid;
    transition: all .5s;
    user-select: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}
```

- output.css

```
.example {
    display: grid;
    transition: all .5s;
    user-select: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}
```

- Laravel version 5.4
- laravel-mix 1.0

How can i enable autoprefixer ?

Comment: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find any documentation on the `mix.styles()` function.
But if you are just wanting to run your stylesheet through postCss you can do this:

```
mix.postCss('resources/css/input.css', 'public/css/output.css', [
    require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 40 versions'],
        grid: true
    })
])
```

Which will output:

```
.example {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(black));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, black);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, white, black);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this is worked. Can mix multiple file to single file

Comment: Yes just add an @import to the above example and mix will combine them. Or use mix.combine(). Or use mix.sass() with .scss or .sass